# how to bind details of columns in a table using session in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, controller, laravel-blade

i have a table which fetch data of various students enrolled for a course from database. Now in this table i want to bind the column for "details" button against a particular student so that it fetches particular details from DB of that specific student

Comment: No one can help you with this little information. Edit your question and post your code

Comment: It's very short please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `Student` model. Than define your `Details` model. One student has many details, so create a `details` relation in the `Student` model.

After that you can set the `$with` property to eager load the relation. Setting the `$visible` property to include the `details` will make the `details` visible when the `Student` gets converted to an array.

```php
class Student extends Model 
{
   $with = ['details'];
   $visible = ['id','name','details'];

   function details () 
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Details::class);
   }
}
```